# Norm of a matrix in a C$^*-$algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

For the C$^*$-algebra $\ $  A=Mat$_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$  and $a\in A$, is the norm of A $$\sup \{ \lVert Ax\rVert \  :\   \lVert x\rVert \leq 1 \} $$ equal to 
$\left( \sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $.

I think this is true. but I have no proof.

Comment: Your sum does not satisfy the triangle inequality so is not a norm e.g if $a=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&2\end{array}\right)$ and $b=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$ then $\| {a+b}\| = \sqrt{13}$ but $\| {a}\| + \|{b}\| = \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2}$. Also, what do you mean by $\|{ax}\|$? Any formula for the induced matrix norm will depend on your vector norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true.

For example, $n=2$, $a=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&2\end{array}\right)$.

Then, $\|a\|=2$, while $\Big(\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|^2\Big)^{1/2}=\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you           .